# What is the distinction between the powers of Farouk and Horus?

Tags: the-mirror-visitor

In *La Passe-Miroir* (The Mirror Visitor) series, by Christelle Dabos, there are various arks, or floating isles. Each has a family spirit with various powers, inherited in part by their descendents.

Now, Farouk of the Pole has mental powers<sup>1</sup> of all sorts. We know that among these powers must be the ability to persuade people to do what he wants,  since one of the minor clans of his descendents, the Persuasives, have this power. However, this seems very similar to the ability of the descendents of Horus, the Pharaohs, whose "charm" seems to involve persuasion.

It seems odd to me for there to be such overlap between spirits' powers, or even for one to be included in the scope of another. Even in the case of Venus, who has mental power over animals, it's made clear that Farouk's family's powers work poorly on animals. What is the difference between the powers of Horus and Farouk?

<sub>1: Although the signature abilities of the Dragons, the claws, allows for bodily damage that cannot, to my mind, be satisfactorily explained through telepathy, unless human minds work *very* differently in that work than in real life—which is certainly a possibility.</sub>